# socket.io with nodejs on a path ( http://localhost:3000/path)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have an application setup which listens on `localhost:3000`

but my requirement is a bit different as I have to use a **path**. `http;//localhost:3000/path`. When I update my `server.js` file, it works `curl localhost:3000/path` and I am getting response from `index.html`. But unable to get response from `socket.io`

Like `http;//localhost:3000/path/socket.io/?` is not working but `http;//localhost:3000/socket.io/?` works. although I have defined this in *index.html*:

```
if (event == 'continue') {
                socket = io.connect('', {
                    path : "/path/socket.io",
                    query: "chatID=" + window.name +
                        "&Authentication=" + sessionStorage.getItem('token') + "&template=" + template + "&AdditionalData=" + additionalD
                });
            }
            else {
                socket = io.connect('', {
                    path : "/path/socket.io",
                    query: "chatID=" + window.name +
                        "&Authentication=" + sessionStorage.getItem('Authentication') + "&template=" + template + "&AdditionalData=" + additionalD
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding `var io = path{"/app"}` in server.js